# Multiple examples in scenario outline gives error(Missing EOF at examples:) in eclipse IDE,How can i solve this?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber

Scenario Outline: Entity test
    Given...
    When...
    Then...

```
@test1
Examples:
|      Entity    |
|      AAA1      |     
|      AAA1      |


@test2
Examples:                               
|     Entity        |
|       BBB01       |
|       BBB02       |
|       BBB03       |
```

### Problem Statement :

1. I have many scenario like above and its prerequisite for few
   scenario to run @test1 data first and then @test2.So i got a
   solution to isolate the data splitting with multiple example.
2. But after creating 2 examples it gives me error in eclipse right
   after example no 2 is "missing EOF at examples" if i keep tags
       on top it gives me error on top of tags right before example 1 is
       "mismatch input '@test1' expecting examples"
3. I have gone through existing answers and version problem in POM i
           have updated the version.And few post says its eclipse IDE issue i cant change IDE as the whole team uses same IDE from long time and comfortable with it ,until and unless very big issue.

### Can anyone please suggest if any solution for Eclipse IDE ? Or POM update is required. I upgraded cucumber pom dependencies to the latest one

### Expected:

The below should be written and executed without any error of eclipse IDE or 
 version dependency error

```
@test1
Examples:To run test 1 specific data
|      Entity    |
|      AAA1      |     
|      AAA1      |


@test2
Examples:  To run test 1 specific data                             
|     Entity        |
|       BBB01       |
|       BBB02       |
|       BBB03       |
```

### Actual:

```
@test1  //Error here -"mismatch input '@test1' expecting examples"
Examples:
|      Entity    |
|      AAA1      |     
|      AAA1      |


@test2
Examples: //Error here if i remove tags -"missing EOF at examples"                               
|     Entity        |
|       BBB01       |
|       BBB02       |
|       BBB03       |
```

Comment: tags can be placed before the scenario outline. If you have same steps for test1 & test2, then you can move those steps to background & use scenario outline to seperate the tables and tags.

Comment: this will work if i have like this one scenario in a feature file.But no ,i have like this scenarios with different steps in a single feature file.And for all the scenario before regression i need to reset the value to @test1.

Comment: What versions of eclipse and cucumber are u using? Can u add the complete scenario outline?

Comment: It looks like cucumber editor plugin issue within eclipse. Can you confirm what is the plugin you are using for editing feature files? I have a cucumber Eclipse Plugin  (developed by cucumber) which works just fine for your case.

Comment: Cucumber plugin-Natural 0.7.6

Comment: the below dependency                                                                  
         '<dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>'

Answer (score 3):

for "missing EOF at examples"   in
Examples:
|address             |
|78 winter walk, USA |

You will need to add **Scenario Outline:** instead of Scenario:

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks for your Answers and support!!*

*Its working now!!*

**What was the problem**-It was cucumber editor issue and i was not able to install any other editor.Please find below the steps i followed and it resolved my problem.

Steps

1. I uninstalled existing cucumber editor from Help->marketplace->serched cucumber 
   editor 
   ,i found 2 results and one was installed in my machine.I uninstalled it.
2. **Clear your eclipse cache with below steps:**
   Open Eclipse and navigate to the Window > Preferences. 
   Scroll down
   the left-hand panel in the Preferences window and click the Remote
   Systems drop-down root menu. Select File Cache. Click the Clear
   Cached Files button in the File Cache window. 
   Note that this will
   automatically close any open remote files on your computer. Press
   Apply and OK to save your changes and exit out of the Preferences
   window. Restart Eclipse Install plugin from eclipse-market place.
   Restart Eclipse again.
3. Try the bellow link. It works for me with Eclipse oxygen.3 it may also work for 
   oxygen.1/oxygen.2
   http://mrpotes.github.com/cukes-jvm-eclipse-plugin/update-site

   Steps:
   Help -> Install New Software -> Work with: http://mrpotes.github.com/cukes-jvm-eclipse- 
   plugin/update-site

After restarting eclipse the 2 examples in the scenario outline are working for me now even with tags.

**Source** -https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/232

Answer (score 0):

write scenario outline on the place of scenario. I am pretty sure then your error will resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was working on Examples files. But  I just got it resolved after I did two things:

1. I updated my gherkin dependency to the stable version
2. I reduced the space between rows
   Then solved .
   That work for me may not work for you as the cause may vary, but try .

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario Outline:** Check login is successful

When user enters  and

Examples:
|username|password|

u get the error because Scenario Outline is missing in the feature
file